# How to set up a WiFi Hotspot using Kubuntu 12.04

Tags: wireless, network-manager, kde, adhoc

I'm not having any luck with the instructions in [Wifi Docs/Ad hoc](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Adhoc) or [Ad-hoc networking](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Ad-hoc_networking). I can't get ad-hoc wifi to work in Kubuntu 12.04 on a Thinkpad X220 with Intel wireless. All indications are that it should work. Any KDE users want to tell me how?

I plan to let other devices connect to my X220 to obtain files. I don't need to share the X220's internet connection. I just want it to act as a WiFi NAS. I would prefer to use WPA security (or better). I also want to do this via the GUI network manager.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Click on NetworkManager icon in the tray.
Press 'Manage Connections'
Go to Wireless Tab
Press 'Add...' button but choose 'Shared'

Everything is ready, I've connected to this connection from the network manager but I dont know if that is important.

Comment: I created a Shared connection, and even connected to it. Does it broadcast the SSID? My other device can't see it. The UI is not geared towards creating a Hotspot at all, unlike on an Android.

Comment: @Prateek: You should also connect to Your own network in a laptop.

Answer (score 1):

KDE also supports easy creating of a hotspot by clicking on the applet and clicking on Hotspot button.

[image]