# How to transfer files from Samsung Galaxy to Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: bluetooth, android, samsung, mtp

I have a Samsung Galaxy GT-S7562 with Android 4.0.4 and Ubuntu 12.04 on a Dell Vostro 1510.

I have just found out I cannot transfer files from Android to Ubuntu with a USB connection because the former uses MTP. gMTP didn't help.

I also found out Ubuntu can't get my Bluetooth working either. So I can't transfer files this way either.

Can I use make a transfer via a wireless network? What other options are left?

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to use [AirDroid](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=airdroid) to transfer files over home WiFi. I sometimes use it and it works well for me.

Comment: So let me get it, I install Airdroid on my phone, what do I install on my laptop? Anything? Does using Airdroid takes data from my SIM?

Comment: Install the app and run it on your phone. It will connect to your home WiFi router and tell you what IP address to type into your laptop browser to log in (eg 192.168.1.2:8888). You can predefine the IP and port if you like. Once logged in, it is guite simple. The app only works on WiFi so will not use your data plan and only works at home (or on the same WiFi network as your laptop).

Comment: If you do not have access to a WiFi router, check out [this for Windows](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/9739/turn-your-windows-7-laptop-into-a-wifi-hotspot-with-connectify/) or [this for Ubuntu Linux](http://www.howtogeek.com/116409/how-to-turn-your-ubuntu-laptop-into-a-wireless-access-point/) to turn your laptop WiFi radio into a hotspot.

Comment: I have Kubuntu 12.04 and cannot follow the second link you gave me. [This](http://askubuntu.com/questions/124144/how-to-set-up-a-wifi-hotspot-using-kubuntu-12-04) seems to be the answer.

Comment: Okay, I created a shared connection, activated it and it shows connected on my laptop. However, it is not picked up by AirDroid which scans other regular WiFi Connections. Did I miss something? (should I post another specific question?)

Comment: If your phone connects to the access point, I would assume Airdroid should see it. Check your IP addresses are ok, and if you're still having problems a specific question might be in order.

Comment: My phone cannot see the access point.

Answer (score 1):

If you use [Dropbox](http://dropbox.com) it has an [Android app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dropbox.android) which you could use to sync files between your computer and your phone.

Comment: This option would require using data credit from both my phone SIM and laptop SIM, it would make transfers expensive, unless I get some free WiFi somewhere. But good one, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps I missed something here... I have a Samsung galaxy as well and I can xfer files to and from Ubuntu without issue via USB. Ubuntu sees my phone as a mass storage device. worse case, you could get a card reader for your laptop and just xfer files between the SD card in your phone and your computer.